# Rollup + React 17 with new JSX Transform - "React is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, rollupjs

I'm trying to prototype a microfrontend architecture with Rollup and a couple of create-react-app applications. However when I locally `yarn link` my external app with the container app, I run into the following error:

ReferenceError: React is not defined

> 23500 | return /*#**PURE***/React.createElement("div", {
> | ^  23501 |   id: "container",
> 23502 |   className: "flex flex-col h-screen"
> 23503 | }, /*#**PURE***/React.createElement(BrowserRouter, null, /*#**PURE***/React.createElement(Header, {

I think it's because we're not importing `React` at the top of every component/file because of React 17's new JSX Transform allowing you to not have to do that. I'd really like to be able to build our micro frontend package without having to import React in every file, is there a way to do this?

Here is the rollup.config.js:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import visualizer from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];

export default {
  input: './src/App.jsx',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'esm',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss(),
    resolve({
      mainFields: ['module', 'main', 'jsnext:main', 'browser'],
      extensions,
    }),
    image(),
    visualizer(),
    includePaths({ paths: ['./'] }),
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      plugins: [
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            root: ['src'],
          },
        ],
      ],
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 5):

In tsconfig.json, add the following code

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  }
}
```

Comment: In my library built using rollup I get this error when I try to do that: Error: 'jsx' is not exported by node_modules\react\jsx-runtime.js, imported by <myComponentPath>

Comment: Same @PCalouche, did you ever find a way around that?

Comment: I never did.  I have to import react to make it work still.

Comment: @PCalouche hope this helps

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/290

Answer (score 5):

Fixed this by adding `{ runtime: "automatic" }` to the `@babel/preset-react` preset.

From the [preset-react runtime docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react#runtime):

> `automatic` auto imports the functions that JSX transpiles to. `classic` does not automatic import anything.

Also mentioned in the [React post about the new JSX transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#manual-babel-setup):

> Currently, the old transform `{"runtime": "classic"}` is the default option. To enable the new transform, you can pass `{"runtime": "automatic"}` as an option to `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` or `@babel/preset-react`

Here's a sample:

```
{
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // ...
        babel({
            // ...
            presets: [
                // ...
                ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```